# How can I separate time from character

Tags: r, string, time

The string is shown as:

```
Fri Sep 07 16:25:06 +0000 2018
```

But I only want to extract

```
16:25:06
```

Comment: You should add the code you have tried yourself, as it will help others. Make sure to check out [help] and [ask] for more info on the workings of SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `as.POSIXct` to convert the string to date-time and then use `format` to extract only the time.

```
format(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"), "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "16:25:06"
```

where

```
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y") #gives
#[1] "2018-09-07 16:25:06 GMT"
```

Check `?strptime` for more details

**data**

```
x <- "Fri Sep 07 16:25:06 +0000 2018"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is not clear but for this Character Vector you can do as below:

```
x <- "Fri Sep 07 16:25:06 +0000 2018"
#substr(x, start, stop)
substr(x, 12, 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ronak suggested you could use 'strptime' and 'strftime' as below.

```
x <- "Fri Sep 07 16:25:06 +0000 2018"
strftime(strptime(x, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT"),"%H:%M:%S")
# [1] "16:25:06"
```

,where strptime convert character to date and
      strftime convert date to character